# Why is my category.php in WP showing all posts?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to configure my category.php in wordpress to show the posts which belong to a specific category.

This is the code of my category.php I'm currently using:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>   
    
    <div id="site-wrapper">
        
        <main id="main">
            
            
            <h2 id="category_title"><a href="#">Kategorie "<?php single_cat_title( '', true ); ?>"</a></h2>
            
                <?php 
                // the query
                $args = array('posts_per_page' => -1 );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
            
                ?>
            
                <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
            
                    <!-- loop -->
            
                    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                     
                                $the_query->the_post(); ?>
           <article id="post_cat"> 
                  
                        <div id="thumbnail">
                        
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
                    
                    </div>
                   
                   <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                   
                   <div class="entry">
                   
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        
                   </div>
                 
           
           </article>
           
 
    
                <?php } } else { ?>
                <p><?php _e( 'Die Posts entsprechen nicht den Kriterien.' ); ?></p>
                <?php }  ?>
       
               <!-- end of the loop -->
 
    
               <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </main>
    
    
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>  
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The code looks good but the problem is that all of the posts which are in index.php are displayed.

I hope that someone could help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the custom query, that is your issue. Your loop should look something like this:

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

        // The rest of your loop code

endwhile;
```

Comment: Damn, I was blind. Thank you so much!!